# Lazy load of css file

Tags: javascript, css, lazy-loading

I'm trying to load additional `css` file using code like this:

```
var doc = document,
    head = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    link = doc.createElement('link'),
    file = link.cloneNode(true);

file.type = 'text/css';
file.rel = 'stylesheet';

file.onload = function () {
    alert('css file is loaded!');
};
file.onerror = function () {
    // 404 error
    alert('Script ' + url + ' wasn\'t loaded! Check file URL');
};

file.href = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';
head.appendChild(file);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3bcp4dy/1/

It's **perfectly works** in CH, FF, Opera 20+, etc.,

but it **doesn't work** in Safari5.1, IOS 5.1, Android 4.2 and less!

Why `onload/onerror` events don't work for `.css` file?

p.s. If I change file to `.js` - `onload` or `onerror` event works.

Comment: look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Browser_compatibility - seems it's just the way it is

Comment: @JaromandaX: I'm seeing `?`, not "not supported," for the ones the OP is asking about...

Comment: clearly MDN don't know - and from the evidence above, one can assume it's not supported - and I **do** know what happens when one assumes

Comment: fortunately, `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css` is CORS enabled, so you can use XMLHttpRequest, or even, fetch (polyfills for fetch and Promise available for internet exploder) to load the css, and stick it in a <style> tag

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, but there is another link below that which defines the behavior for iOS/Android - https://pie.gd/test/script-link-events/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thx for link, all is clear now :)

Comment: @RGraham: Good link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If notification is unreliable, you can poll to see the new stylesheet arrive, see comments:

```
(function() {
    // Remember how many stylesheets there are
    var old = document.styleSheets.length;

    // Set a timeout
    var timeout = Date.now() + 30000;

    // Watch for new arrivals
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (document.styleSheets.length > old) {
            console.log("Got it! " + document.styleSheets.length);
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else if (Date.now() > timeout) {
            console.log("Give up");
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);

    // Add the stylesheet link
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    link.onload = function() {
        console.log("Got it, clearing timer");
        clearInterval(timer);
        // ...
    };
    link.onerror = function() {
        console.log("Got error, clearing timer");
        clearInterval(timer);
        // ...
    };
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(link);
})();
```

The advantage to this over using an ajax request is that you don't need CORS.

**Note:** I used `Date.now` above for convenience, you'll need to shim/polyfill it (or not use it) on some of the browsers you mention. The shim/polyfill is trivial:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {
        return +new Date;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fortunately, `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css` is CORS enabled, so you can use XMLHttpRequest, or even, fetch

Using fetch

```
fetch('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(text) {
    var style = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
    style.textContent = text;
    console.log('style loaded');
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('style load failed with error', err);
});
```

Polyfill for fetch - https://github.com/github/fetch you'll probably also need a polyfill for Promise if you need one for fetch - https://www.promisejs.org/#browser

You can use XMLHttpRequest too, if you want

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('style loaded', this.responseText);
});
xhr.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.error('style load failed');
});
xhr.send();
```

And if you are writing for browsers from the stone age, there are ways to achieve the same thing using ActiveX rubbish and some weird cross domain hack in internet explorer - use it or whatever

Comment: *"You can use XMLHttpRequest too, if you want"* Well, not on IE8 or IE9. :-)

Comment: I stopped caring about windows XP years ago - if you want to run XP, don't use IE - simple solution

Comment: Seeing as the OP doesn't even mention internet exploder, then you have a cows opinion :p

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, it's not up to you (or me), and people [still use the darned thing](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), the fools. The OP's post is quite clearly about supporting old browsers. (Nice Friends reference! I *love* that scene.)

Comment: I do see your point. Best way to stop people using the damned thing is to stop bending over backwards trying to support it :D - ahhh, you got the moo point :p ... **OH MY** 18% of the world still use IE8/9 !!

Comment: If you can ignore >11% of your possible visitors, **great for you**. I certainly don't support IE8 in applications, and if possible use actual site stats to see if it's necessary for a given site. But the numbers tell us we can't just issue a blanket "who cares about IE8" yet. Maybe next year. Of course, if possible, I'll just disable a feature and invite them to install a decent browser. :-)

Comment: `Maybe next year` - yeah, I remember hearing that about IE6 for too many years.

Comment: We got there in the end. We will this time, too.